# How do I transform a child element o uppercase if a child element with the same name exists?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that looks like this:

..
`<PersonalInfo>

    <LastName>Smith</LastName>

  ...

</PersonalInfo>

<DependentInfo>

    <LastName>Johnson</LastName>

  ...

</DependentInfo>

...`

and I need to convert the last name of the dependent to upper case.

I wrote this XSLT

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(//LastName, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
```

It converts  last name of the dependent to the last name of the personal info in upper case. So it converts it to SMITH and I want it to be converted to JOHNSON.
Could someone tell me how I can do this?
Thanks you very much.

Comment: `//LastName` means any `LastName` element in the document. Then `fn:traslate` takes the first node from that node set. So, it will be always evaluate to the same string value... You should tell us what the context for that `xsl:value-of`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for certain based on the XML example and the small XSL snippet, but it sounds like the context where you use the `xsl:value-of` is `DependentInfo`. By using `//LastName` in the `translate()` function, you're telling the processor to select any `LastName` in the XML. (In this case it appears to be selecting the first occurrence of `LastName` in `PersonalInfo`.)

Try removing the `//` from your `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(LastName, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
```

If this doesn't work, try posting more of your XSL for us to look at.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(DependentInfo/LastName, $smallcase, $uppercase)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
translate(/*/DependentInfo/LastName, $smallcase, $uppercase)
```